# Insert, Update Trigger check if dates overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Flight (
  flightnumber         INT                  NOT NULL,
  departuretime        DATETIME             NOT NULL,
  arrivaltime          DATETIME             NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE PassengerForFlight (
  passengernumber      INT                  NOT NULL,
  flightnummer         INT                  NOT NULL,
)
```

Now i wanna write a trigger thats check on **PassengerForFlight**: if the passenger not book a flight on overlap dates.

My attempt for the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM PassengerForFlight PV inner join FlightV ON PV.flightnumber=   V.flightnumber
WHERE PV.passengernumber = (SELECT passengernumber
                            FROM Inserted I) 
                            AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                      FROM Flight V1
                                      WHERE V.departuretime BETWEEN V1.departuretime AND V1.arrivaltime  
                                      OR V.arrivaltime  BETWEEN V1.departuretime AND V1.arrivaltime )
```

Anyone a idea? I can't figure it out how i check the inserted value on the already existing data in the tables

For example i got these  data:

```
Table Flight
INSERT Vlucht(flightnumber, depaturetime,arrivaltime)
  VALUES ( 5314,  '2004-01-30 11:30', '2004-02-01 11:30' );
INSERT Vlucht(flightnumber, depaturetime,arrivaltime)
  VALUES ( 5315,  '2004-01-31 11:30', '2004-02-02 11:30' );

Tabel PersonForFlight
INSERT PassengerForFlight(passengernumber,flightnummer) VALUES ( 850,  5314);
```

Now with this data i wanna insert a new flight for passengernumber 850

```
INSERT PassengerForFlight(passengernumber,flightnummer) VALUES ( 850,  5315);
```

This must be not allowed because the times from flight 5314 and 5315 overlap eath other

Thanx for help!

Comment: Please explain what this means:  " if the passenger not book a flight on overlap dates.".  Sample data and desired results might help.

Comment: You want to ensure that no passenger is booked on multiple flights such that the flights overlap? (but, presumably you're fine with one flight starting immediately after another flight ends, no transfer time, so this isn't real world?)

Comment: @GordonLinoff added some data, hopefully is cleary now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, You are missing primary keys and foreign keys in your tables - I would write the tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Flight (
    flightnumber         INT                  NOT NULL,
    departuretime        DATETIME             NOT NULL,
    arrivaltime          DATETIME             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Flight PRIMARY KEY (flightnumber)
);

CREATE TABLE PassengerForFlight (
    passengernumber      INT                  NOT NULL,
    flightnummer         INT                  NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT FK_PassengerForFlight_Flight FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Flight(flightnumber),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PassengerForFlight PRIMARY KEY (passengernumber, flightnummer)
);
```

Second, you can use an instead of insert trigger to handle overlapping flights for the same person:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_PassengerForFlight_IOI ON PassengerForFlight
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

    INSERT INTO PassengerForFlight (passengernumber, flightnummer)
    SELECT passengernumber, flightnummer
    FROM Inserted I
    INNER JOIN  Flight F1 ON I.flightnummer = F1.flightnumber
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM PassengerForFlight P
        INNER JOIN Flight F2 ON P.flightnummer = F2.flightnumber
        WHERE P.passengernumber = I.passengernumber AND P.flightnummer <> I.flightnummer
        AND F2.departuretime <= F1.arrivaltime -- here is the test for overlapping dates
        AND F1.departuretime <= F2.arrivaltime -- here is the test for overlapping dates
    )

GO
```

To test the trigger I've added another flight that doesn't overlap the existing ones, and tried adding the same passenger to all 3 flights:

```
INSERT INTO Flight (flightnumber, departuretime, arrivaltime) VALUES 
( 5314,  '2004-01-30 11:30', '2004-02-01 11:30' ),
( 5315,  '2004-01-31 11:30', '2004-02-02 11:30' ), 
( 5316,  '2004-02-03 11:30', '2004-02-05 11:30' );

INSERT INTO PassengerForFlight(passengernumber,flightnummer) VALUES ( 850,  5314);
```

Note that the next insert statement attempts to insert the same passenger number to 2 different flights:

```
INSERT INTO PassengerForFlight(passengernumber,flightnummer) VALUES ( 850,  5315), ( 850,  5316);
```

Test:

```
SELECT *
FROM PassengerForFlight
```

Results:

```
passengernumber flightnummer
850             5314
850             5316
```

Comment: You might want to consider what happens with `INSERT ... VALUES (2,5314),(2,5315);`, that is, an insert that itself contains rows that conflict

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good point, but what should we do in such a case? Should we insert one or none of the conflicting rows? That's for the OP to decide...

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a think how to avoid inserting before it happens rather than using a trigger.

This could be addressed in your UI but in back end you could write some SQL and do a check

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Check here if the passenger is booked on any flights that overlap the date) 
BEGIN
     INSERT PassengerForFlight(passengernumber,flightnummer) VALUES ( 850,  5315);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want to return results if there is or if there isn't an overlap. Either way, to check for an overlap, you generally want a where clause something like this:

```
WHERE
    flightA.DepartureTime < flightB.ArrivalTime AND
    flightA.ArrivalTime > flightB.DepartureTime
```